# Find the sum of length of the selected lines using shell script?

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I want to print sum of the selected lines in file.

For example, a file with following lines starting line with 'sss':

```
sss              
nnnn      
rrrrr          
ttt         
eeee        
gg    
h      
l     
k           
ooo  
ppp
```

I want to print the value of the sum of the lengths of lines 2,6,10. 
For this input file: 4+2+3 and output: 9.

Comment: Look's like a homework, but I gave you an answer =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk 'NR==2||NR==6||NR==10{sum+=length($0)}END{print sum}' file.txt
```

- `NR` is the current line number
- `||` is a **OR** statement
- what is preceding `{}` is the **condition**
- what's in `{}` is the **action**
- `sum+=length($0)` increment the variable sum with the length of the current line
- the `END` block is executed @the end when all lines have been read

Comment: +1 and could be abbreviated to `awk 'NR~/^(2|6|10)$/{sum+=length($0)}END{print sum}' file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
  echo "$(($(sed -n 's/ *$//;2p;6p;10p' file.txt | wc -c)-3))"
```

This will print out via `sed` the total characters in the list of lines (`2p;6p;10p;` you can change this to whatever you want) using `wc` to count the characters in each line, we take off 3 because of the newlines you could build the string in a script just make sure to adjust the number 3 to however many lines you print out.

Answer (score 0):

In BASH (as a one liner with line-continuations for readability, executed in a subshell)

```
( sum=0; n=0; lines=126; while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do \
((n++)); [[ "$lines" =~ "$n" ]] && ((sum+=${#line})); done <dat/lineln.dat; \
echo -e "\n  sum of lines '$lines': $sum\n" )
```

**input:**

```
$ cat dat/lineln.dat
sss
nnnn
rrrrr
ttt
eeee
gg
h
l
k
ooo
ppp
```

**output:**

```
  sum of lines '126': 9
```